# SonataFormatterBundle twig extension: Template "..." is not defined

Tags: symfony, twig, markdown, formatter, sonata

My twig template file

```
{{ 'Hello *world*' | format_text('markdown') }}
```

Error:

```
Template "<p>Hello <em>world</em></p>" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a BC break in the SonataFormatterBundle. You can revert to version 3.2.0 or apply a patch. As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataFormatterBundle/issues/248).